# How do I merge into the last non-merge commit?

Tags: git

I've been keeping my local branch up to date with master by doing `git pull origin master --rebase`, such that i can do `git commit --amend` to keep a nice history.

but the last time I ran `git pull origin master --rebase`, it appears to have done a merge commit.

So now my git log looks like this:

```
      1 commit 24f13d1601ffcd3169d6449290722207ff336ebc (HEAD -> do_a_thing)
      2 Merge: b7e39aa4 7b49f585
      3 Author: mark <mark@example.com>
      4 Date:   Thu Feb 6 17:55:29 2020 -0800
      5
      6     Merge branch 'master' of <repo> into do_a_thing
      7
      8 commit b7e39aa40726e09c1a516ee63f91088b4114808b
      9 Author: mark <mark@example.com>
     10 Date:   Mon Feb 3 17:27:07 2020 -0800
     11
     12     foo
     13
     14 commit 7b49f58526ca94aaa9c71a8074fcd650fad2ac73 (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
     15 Author: Jenkins <no-reply+jenkins@example.com>
     16 Date:   Thu Feb 6 13:58:36 2020 -0800
     17
     18     - foo@1.0.0
     19     - bar@1.0.0
     20     - baz@0.0.1
     21     - qux@1.4.1
     22
     23 commit e13abeded9535e18cb3dff8044abdfde2f213655
     24 Merge: a772961b 0fd88c29
     25 Author: Jenkins <no-reply+jenkins@example.com>
     26 Date:   Thu Feb 6 13:57:00 2020 -0800
     27
     28     Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/i/stuff'
...
```

I want to "merge" onto b7e39aa40726e09c1a516ee63f91088b4114808b, so I can rename it, and keep a squashed local branch.

How can I do this? Not sure how to use rebase in this instance.

Thanks!

Comment: That looks like a `git pull` run *without* the `--rebase` option (maybe you left it off?). In any case, just rebase now to get rid of it. I recommend avoiding `git pull` entirely: run `git fetch` yourself (`git pull` would do this for you), then run the second command that `git pull` would have run for you yourself. That way you can't accidentally `git pull` such that it runs `git merge`.

Comment: ah, must be. or i think maybe there was a conflict, forcing a merge commit. anyway, thanks!

How would I "just rebase now to get rid of it." ? I can't just swap the order of 24f13d1601ffcd3169d6449290722207ff336ebc and b7e39aa40726e09c1a516ee63f91088b4114808b .... can i?

Comment: Rebase works by copying commits, but discarding merges. So with `git rebase origin/master` you'll copy any commits you have on your current branch, that aren't already on `origin/master` (and aren't merge commits), so that they come after the last commit that *is* on `origin/master` ... which is what `git pull --rebase` would have done.